# Using spservices module

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, spfx, spfx-webparts, spfx-tooling

I have a SPFx web part I'm trying to include spServices in. I've done the `npm install` for jquery@2 and spServices, run `npm install` in the project root directory, and tried to run `grunt` (as outlined in the [README](https://github.com/sympmarc/SPServices)). However, I'm getting `Fatal error: Unable to find Gruntfile.`

Since `grunt` wasn't working, I tried adding

```
"externals": {
"jquery":{
  "path": "/node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "globalName": "jquery"
},
"sps": {
  "path": "/node_modules/spservices/dist/jquery.SPServices.js"   ,
  "globalName": "GetUserProfile"
}  
}
```

to my config.json file (as outlined [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/retrieve-user-details-using-spservices-in-sharepoint-framework-development-model/)), but when i add `import sps` in my .js file (script file alongside the .ts file) I'm getting the following in the workbench (**THANKS TO u/Oskar FOR RESOLVING THIS PORTION**):
[image: SP ERROR]

What do I need to do to get spServices to import properly?

**Edit:** Updated above with changes from u/Oskar's response. 
Now, I'm receiving the following error in the console:

[image: Console Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you reference the externals wrong. Shouldn't it be this way?

```
"sps": {
    "path": "/externalLibraries/jquery.SPServices.min.js",
    "globalName": "sps"
  }
```

and then in your .tsx files

```
import * as sps from 'sps';
```

Comment: I updated accordingly, and initially it wasn't working because apparently I needed to point at the `.js` file instead of the `.min.js` file. Thanks a bunch!!

Comment: Hmmm, actually... now my part is rendering fine, but console still shows an error. I'll update the original post.

Comment: I would download directly from http://sympmarc.github.io/SPServices/  and use it in the "traditional" way: create a folder and add the .js file into your project. Without using the npm.